# How to parameterize a variable value inside an URL/path in Load runner

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner, parameterization

Currently I am working in an application where I have to pass new value from a text file to the request path itself.In the below link I have to pass category ID values from text file.The request path is as following: **/app1/hierarchy.save.action?category=11**. Please suggest how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are new to loadrunner.
Refer VUGEN Guide - Topic: Parametrization.

**Quick solution:**
Select the data to be parameterized(in your case it is 11)
Right Click -> Replace with paramter -> Crete New Parameter
Provide Parameter name and click OK.

Note: This creates a file with parameter name in script folder.
Press Ctrl+L to view or edit the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

See section in training material, tutorial and VUGEn guide related to parameterization.

Your manager should not be asking you to deliver in services without proper training nor a mentor available internally.  It is unfair to you and to your end client.  This manager is setting you and the client up for very low value and very likely failure on the services delivered